# Path text gets distorted when converting PSD to PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, pdf, export

So, I've got this huge PSD file and I need to convert it to PDF. What I do is: File > Automate > PDF Presentation. I do that all the time and I've never had a problem with it but this time things were different. Part of the text I was using had to follow a circle, so it had a curvature that I created by using the typo tool on a circle path. And on Photoshop it looks good but when I convert to PDF this is what I get:

[image]
I have no idea how to fix this! I tried to rasterize all layers with typography but didn't work.

Do you guys have any idea how to keep the text curvature untouched after the PDF convertion?

Comment: You get the same problem even if you rasterize the type?? Could you share a screenshot of how it looks in PS?

Comment: This is how it looks on Photoshop: http://puu.sh/pSorO/52d4fe8d8f.jpg

And yeah, same problem after rasterize the type.

It only worked after I merge all layers together! No idea why, tho.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you not use Illustrator for stuff like this?

Comment: @joojaa, because I don't know Illustrator at all. :c

Comment: Yes but you can not learn if you never consider change. This one of the situations where illustrator is clearly better and this is a simple case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to flatten all the layers and save out that way. Obviously make a copy or try not to save over your PSD. Or "merge to new layer" and try exporting that way.

Comment: I tried what you said and it worked! Thank you so much!

Now I'm curious: why that weird thing happened before flattering all layers?

Comment: I'm so glad it worked. Cheers!

Comment: @LucianoInfanti don't forget to mark the answer as valid if it solves your question